# Drupal first module -- 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-modules

This is my first module. I have been trying to successfully install my module since a week now.

I have gone through every line. Even the schema is being installed and entry is made at system table. But still after enabling the module It shows 500 Internal Server Error until I delete the entry from system table.

Please guide me what I am doing wrong.

*Note: sisattribute table is already created in drupal database*

My .install file

```
<?php

/**
* @file
*/

function sisinstitute_install() {
 drupal_install_schema('sisinstitute');
 variable_set('node_options_sisinstitute', array('status'));

 $attributes = array();

 $attributes['Country'] = array(
  'US' => 'United States of America',
  'AD' => 'Andorra',
  'AE' => 'United Arab Emirates',
  'AF' => 'Afghanistan',
 );

$s = "INSERT INTO {sisattribute} (domain, akey, avalue, weight) VALUES ('%s', '%s', '%s', %d)";
$prevdomain = '';
$weight = 0;
foreach ($attributes as $domain => $attribute) {
if ($domain != $prevdomain) $weight=0;
foreach ($attribute as $key => $value) {
  db_query($s, $domain, $key, $value, $weight);
  $weight++;
}
$prevdomain = $domain;
}
}

function sisinstitute_disable() {
drupal_set_message(t('Please note that they will now have reduced functionality, and will not be protected by previous access controls.'), 'warning');
}

function sisinstitute_uninstall() {
 drupal_uninstall_schema('sisinstitute');

db_query($s = "DELETE FROM {sisattribute} WHERE domain IN ('Country')");
}

function sisinstitute_schema() {
  $schema['sisinstitute'] = array(
   'fields'        => array(
    'vid'         => array('type' => 'int', 'not null' => TRUE, 'default' => 0),
    'nid'         => array('type' => 'int', 'not null' => TRUE, 'default' => 0),
    'country'     => array('type' => 'varchar', 'length' => 100),
    'www'         => array('type' => 'varchar', 'length' => 100),
    'phone'       => array('type' => 'varchar', 'length' => 100),
    'email'       => array('type' => 'varchar', 'length' => 50),
    'provstate'   => array('type' => 'varchar', 'length' => 50),
    'zip'         => array('type' => 'varchar', 'length' => 10),
    'city'        => array('type' => 'varchar', 'length' => 100),
    'address'     => array('type' => 'varchar', 'length' => 100),
    'orglanguage' => array('type' => 'varchar', 'length' => 100),
    'isactive'    => array('type' => 'int', 'default' => 1),

  ),
  'primary key' => array('vid'),
  'indexes' => array(
  'nid'     => array('nid')
  ),
  );

  return $schema; 
  }
```

And my .module file:

```
<?php
// $Id$

/**
*@File
*Module for Institution support in SIS package
*/


/**
*hook_help()
*/


/**
*hook_menu()
*/




/**
*hook_perm()
*/
function sisinstitute_perm() {
  return array('access institute', 'create institute', 'edit institute', 'delete institute', 'view belonged institute', 'view all institutes');

}






/**
*hook_access()
*/
function sisinstitute_access($op, $node. $account=NULL) {
 if (empty($account)) {
  global $user;
  $account = $user;
 }

 if (is_numeric($node)) $node = node_load($node);

 if (!isset($account->sisinstitute_nid) && module_exists('sisstudent')) {
  _sisstudent_load($account);
 }

 if (!isset($account->sisinstitute_nid) && module_exists('sisstaff')) {
  _sisstaff_load($account);
 }

 switch($op) {
  case 'create': return user_access('create institute', $account);
  case 'update': return user_access('edit institute', $account);
  case 'delete': return user_access('delete institute', $account);
  case 'view'  : {
                  if (user_access('view all institutes', $account))
                    return TRUE;
                  elseif (user_access('view belonged institute', $account) && $account->sisinstitute_nid == $node->nid)
                    return TRUE;
                  else return FALSE;
                 }
 }
}




/**
*hook_node_info()
*/

function sisinstitute_node_info() {
 return array(
  'sisinstitute' => array(
  'name' => t('Institute'),
  'module' => 'sisinstitute',
  'description' => t("Institute for SIS"),
  'title_label' => t("Name"),
  'body_label' => t("Note"),
)
);

}



/**
*hook_form()
*/
function sisinstitute_form(&$node) {
 $type = node_get_types('type', $node);

 //$form['#attributes']['class'] = 'sismcomponent_node_form';

 $form['title'] = array(
  '#type' => 'textfield',
  '#title' => check_plain($type->title_label),
  '#required' => TRUE,
  '#default_value' => $node->title,
  // '#weight' => module_exists('content') ? content_extra_field_weight($node->type, 'title') : -18,
  );


$form['isactive'] = array(
 '#type' => 'checkbox',
 '#title' => t('Active'),
 '#default_value' => $node->isactive,
);

return $form;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm Got it:-)(after 8 hours)

function sisinstitute_access($op, $node. $account=NULL) {

has a period instead of a comma after $node

Comment: omg that was a little syntax mistake :)
Congratulations on getting started in module development. See  http://drupal.org/node/158043 for a guide to get wsod and 500 errors fixed.